# Limit of $n(1-U_{n:n})$.

Tags: probability, order-statistics

Let $U_{n:n}$ be n-th order statistic of uniform distribution on segment [0,1]. 
Let's think about $n(1-U_{n:n})$. I'm supposed to find its limit for n approaching $\infty$. And another question is: how it converges? By probability? Almost surely? I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what is an order statistic on a segment?

Comment: I'm sorry, of course I meant order statistic of unifrom distribution on line segment. Thanks for finding my mistake.

Comment: 55 questions asked, 9 months on the site, and yet somehow the concept of adding some personal input to your questions did not go through... until now?

Comment: Have a look at this document : http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/~hchen/teaching/LargeSample/notes/noteorder.pdf it might help you !